# Indicating a subject and objective thoughts of inevitability

Tags: syntax, expressions, modality

How do the Japanese show the nuance between the inevitable outcomes of actions based on their thoughts versus their findings?

After the Tsunami of 2011, Japanese Volcanologists predict an inevitable eruption (due to the tsunami).

**２０１１年の津波の後で、日本の火山学の博士が、富士山はずっと爆発します。**

Unfortunately I believe that my (incorrectly written) attempt fails to show that its due to their research that they believe the outcome will occur.

Comment: I don't know enough grammar to answer your question, but rather than use the phrase "volcanologists predict an ...", why not use the words "volcanologists' research indicates an ..." ... to totally sidestep your problem?

Comment: It is a valid point, however my final intention is to then substitute my own logic to indicate what I believe may happen. However since they use facts to base their answer where as mine will be more of a feeling or intuition, I felt it was better to understand how to show the two different trains of thought.

Comment: Sorry but the way this question is phrased is confusing. What do you mean by "inevitable outcomes of actions based on their thoughts"? Do you mean "predictions based on research" vs "predictions based on guesswork" ?

Comment: Part of the confusion here may stem from the English phrasing not being so clear. We don't really say someone predicts (aka guesses) something that is inevitable (100%) going to happen. Is your question specifically about how to phrase forecasting or more generally about contrasting varying levels of certainty?

Comment: Yes. I must apologise for my ineptitude to carry across my question. The question relates to how the Japanese express predictions based on research and usage of facts, versus how someone, uneducated on the matter, would deliver their own prediction based only on their opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

- ～[ことになる](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B)だろう (A handy combination, "... will end up ～". Add 必ず, 確実に or 間違いなく to increase certainty)
- ～(こと)は避けられないだろう (more explicit "... is inevitable")
- ～(こと)は[不可避](http://jisho.org/word/%E4%B8%8D%E5%8F%AF%E9%81%BF)だろう (more rigid than 避けられない)

ずっと is "always", not "certainly". Volcanic eruption is usually 噴火.

For example

> - 富士山の噴火は避けられないだろう。
> - 2011年の津波によって富士山は間違いなく噴火することになるだろう。